# Node.js SSL error: wrong version number: ../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332

Tags: node.js, openssl, node-fetch

Using Node.js and cross-fetch, I receive an error accessing an HTTPS site (see title and comments below). There is no proxy involved. The code below is a simplified version that reproduces the error. The comments in the code contain the exact error text.

This had been working until something (?) changed, which leads me to believe a server-side change, which I have no access to. However, Tampermonkey JS scripts that do the same requests using GM_xmlhttpRequest still work correctly.

Any debugging suggestions, or why the "wrong version number" is generated?

Edit: looking in the debugger at the call to `tlssock.connect(options, tlssock._start);` the 'ciphers' option is set to `ciphers: "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!SRP:!CAMELLIA"`  and the 'port' option is 443. In the TLSSocket member, I didn't see anything that jumped out at me relating to a version number.

```
const fetch = require('cross-fetch');
const testURL = 'https://api.torn.com/faction/?selections=upgrades&key=xxxxxxxxxx';

fetch(testURL).then(res => {
    console.log('[TEST] res: ', res);
}).then(data => {
    console.log('[TEST] data: ', data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error("[TEST] error: ", err);
});

/*
Output:
[TEST] error:  FetchError: request to https://api.torn.com/faction/?selections=upgrades&key=xxxxxxxxxx failed, 
               reason: write EPROTO 140735681590144:
               error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:
               wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/edlau/Documents/Torn-JS/Fac-chat-generic/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  code: 'EPROTO'
}*/
```

Edit 2: I updated node.js to the latest, with the same results, versioning info is as follows:

```
npm version
{
  facchat: '2.0.0',
  npm: '8.3.0',
  node: '17.3.0',
  v8: '9.6.180.15-node.12',
  uv: '1.42.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '102',
  nghttp2: '1.45.1',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '3.0.1+quic',
  cldr: '40.0',
  icu: '70.1',
  tz: '2021a3',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
```

Edit 3: Using CURL (to the same URL):
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this for hours, reducing it to just using curl and various options, none of which worked - it finally did again. With no options. My test code works as well now. So I conclude that it was server side 'maintainance' going on, or being routed to different servers, the server is hosted, near as I can tell, in a cloudflare environment.

So although I can't say for certain *what* was causing this, I can no longer reproduce it.